How to cut a u-lock?
Lost all keys to my U-lock and need to cut it. Tried a heavy duty bolt cutter, but there was ZERO give. Is an angle grinder the next thing to try? If so, what size is best and what kind of wheel should I buy. I see wheels for sale that say "for stainless steel", but I'm not sure if that means a sheet of steel which would be a different ballgame.

The whole point of those locks is that they arre highly resistant to physical attack, including bolt cutters. Grinding should work eventually.

The make of the U-lock might help.  A fast search said some can be open with a pen.

You should first try a grinder briefly on the U, and also a drill briefly on the barrel of the lock.  You might find one makes better progress than the other.  Drill out the pins if that's easier.  Even if it isn't, if it does make progress, it's safer for you and the bike.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

An angle grinder is the way to go. The metal cutting "for stainless steel" variety are exactly what you need, made from diamond or carbide. The best size depends on your wheel and how long you want to sit by your bike cutting it, even a dremel tool will work eventually. A huge wheel on a powerful grinder will be hard to muster. The biggest challenge is the grinder skittering off the lock and gouging the frame. Try to cut away the butyl covering with a knife before-hand. You can even try to brace the lock somewhat while guarding the frame by shoving an odd length of wood into the lock. There will be sparks. Source: kid hid my lock key into the couch which I didn't find til two years later.

Do you have room to fit a small bottle-jack between the arms of the lock? If so, put one in and pump away. It will break the lock side of the crossbar, which is the weak point.

I've never seen a bottle jack that small.

Normally this is done with a (stolen) scissor jack rather than a bottle jack.

If you have more time and muscles than money, you can buy an abrasive rod hacksaw blade for less than $10. It will take a long time and you'll probably hate your decision at the halfway point, but it will eventually do the job. Keep the rod good and tight to reduce flexing that shortens life.
